# Floating-point arithmetic - bits of the exponent

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, epsilon

I have a general question about floating-point arithmetic.

Recently, I got quite interested in understanding of the computing in programmes, thus I started to solve exercises. I would like you to explain the one which especially confuses me:

> Compute machine epsilon (not only as a decimal value, but also as
>   **the number of the bits of the binary exponent**). Does machine epsilon depend on the number of bits of the mantissa or the number of bits of the exponent?

Here are my calculus:

```
def exponent():
    expon = 0
    for number in range(1000):
         if 1.0+2.0**(-number)>1.0:
             expon = number
    return expon

print(exponent())
print(2**(exponent())) # Prints decimal value
```

Output:

```
52
2.220446049250313e-16
```

Is it correct? I have a problem with interpretation of the bolded text. Do I have to determine whether it is 8 or 11 bits? How can I do that? Is it right assumption, that the epsilon depends on the number of bits of the mantissa, because they determine the precision of the float?

Answer (score 0):

The text you wrote is poorly written. It is not clear what it would mean to calculate a number “as the number of the bits of the binary exponent”. For example, if the number of bits of the binary exponent is 11, what would it mean to calculate a number as 11? If somebody said “Calculate 7 times 13 as 11,” that would be meaningless.

The so-called machine epsilon, the difference between 1 and the next greater representable number, depends solely on the number of digits (bits for base 2) available for the significand.<sup>1</sup>

2<sup>−52</sup> is the machine epsilon for IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point. Since it has a 53-bit significand (52 bits encoded explicitly, one encoded via the exponent field), when the high bit represents 2<sup>0</sup>, as it must for numbers between 1 and 2, the low bit of the significand represents 2<sup>−52</sup>.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> “Significand” is the preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point number. A mantissa is the fraction portion of a logarithm.